# how to assign typedef variables as static

Tags: c++

can anyone please tell me the mistake in the below program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
        public:
        typedef int count;
        static count cnt ;

};

count A::cnt = 0;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

### error

count does not name a type

Answer (score 13):

You would have to use `A::count A::cnt = 0;` as your typedef is defined within the scope of class A.

i.e. either move the typedef outside the class or use scope resolution as above.

Comment: @bash.d Of course it works, you can scope a `typedef` in the same way as any other type. https://ideone.com/EcCrlU

Comment: + good to know it's a standard construct and should compile on all platforms. I do this all the time, albeit implicitly, with templates.

Answer (score 2):

Your `typedef` is inside your class and as such not globally available.

You would need to

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int count;


class A
{
        public:
        static count cnt ;

};

count A::cnt = 0;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to make it global, as @Bathsheba's answer shows.

Comment: Yes, you don't need, but you can. And if I knew about what @Bathsheba wrote, I'd suggested it, too. But I didn't...

Comment: I downvoted because you say they need to make the typedef global, which isn't true. It is also better to keep reduce the scope of the typedef and keep the association.

Comment: This solution is absolutely valid! In in this particular case right. So there is no reason to downvote.

Comment: It works, yes, but it isn't needed (which is what you say), and it introduces a global symbol (which is poor practice). It's not a good answer.

Comment: Not sure what just happened there. Peace.